# Клонирование объектов Java

Tags: java, ооп, классы, объекты, клонирование

В классе main есть: 
 1) класс сlass1 в котором есть двумерный массив и еще несколько переменных 
 2) функция func(class1 cl) которая принимает объект класса но возвращает другой тип данных (float), при этом внутри тела функции проводятся манипуляции с двумерным массивом класса что бы получить ответ

Так вот, проблема в том, что если я создам экземпляр класса, вызову функцию и передам его туда, то после этого исходный массив объекта меняется (Что мне естественно не нужно) 
Я нашел решение в виде метода clone(), но хеш-код объектов то стал другим, а вот хеш-код полей внутри клона объекта тот же, и соответственно при изменении массива одного объекта изменяется массив другого

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить эту проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте class1 сериализуемым (добавьте `implements Serializable` в его определение).

Сохраняем объекта класса в поток байтов:
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream ous = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        ous.writeObject(new class1());
        ous.close();

теперь в `func` можно передать `(class1)new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray())).readObject()`

Таким образом объект класса сохраняется в поток из которого восстанавливаться **независимый** клон.

Comment: Что такое baos ?

Comment: @BogdanBida ByteArrayOutputStream очевидно

Comment: тогда я не понял что и куда передавать, на месте new ByteArrayOutputStream() что должно быть?

Comment: @BogdanBida исправил

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы метод `clone` клонировал поля объекта, его нужно переопределить в самом классе. По умолчанию он оперирует только примитивными типами и указателями

Но Вам нужно просто скопировать массив. Для этого есть метод `Arrays.copyOf()` или банально вызвать `clone` для массива

Вот тут описаны разные методы получения копии массива https://stackoverflow.com/a/36513254/5376639

Comment: Но ведь при изменении клонированного объекта изменяется и родительский, на что и указывает автор

Comment: @pinguin Если я правильно понял автора, то он вызывает метод `clone` без его переопределения. А потому получает всего лишь копию ссылки на массив

Comment: но если автор говорит что использовал `clone`, то он ее точно переопределял (она же protected)